# В чем ошибка при перегрузке оператора+?

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Перегружаю бинарный + в своем классе:

```
MyClass operator+(const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b) {
    ...
    return a.value + b.value;
}
```

Получаю ошибку `бинарный оператор + имеет слишком много параметров`. В чем проблема? Везде указывается именно такая сигнатура перегрузки этого оператора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Каждая не статическая функция-член класса имеет неявный параметр, который получает значение `this`, то есть указатель на сам объект класса.

Вам надо либо этот оператор определить в классе как дружественную функцию (если требуется обращение к закрытым или защищенным членам класса), например

```
friend MyClass operator+(const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b) {
    ...
    return a.value + b.value;
}
```

Или объявить ее как обычную функцию вне класса, если не требуется обращение к закрытым или защищенным членам класса.

Либо сделать оператор функцией-членом класса, но с одним явным параметром

```
MyClass operator+( const MyClass &b) const {
    ...
    return this->value + b.value;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я помнил, что `this` применяется, но сбило с толку, что везде пишут 2 параметра. Теперь всё ясно.

Answer (score 2):

В классе он должен перегружаться с одним аргументом. Второй аргумент - объект самого класса.

Если вы создаете его как свободную функцию (вне класса) - все верно, именно такая сигнатура и должна быть.